# simpelXMLElement attribute namespaces

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I looking into this problem for a few days now and need some help with it.
I want to access the namespaced attributes for the 'inhoud' element.
In this case, for example, I want the attribute value from the contentType attribute. So I want to grab the 'text/plain' value.

```
<inhoud p10:contentType="text/plain" p6:bestandsnaam="hallo 2.txt" xmlns:p10="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">aGFsbG8gZGFhciB4DQoNCg0K</inhoud>
```

It's prefixed with the p10 namespace.

Below the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <updateZaakdocument_Di02 xmlns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310">
            <edcLk02 p6:entiteittype="EDC" p6:functie="update" xmlns:p6="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301">
                <parameters>
                    <p6:mutatiesoort>W</p6:mutatiesoort>
                </parameters>
                <object p6:entiteittype="EDC" p6:sleutelVerzendend="934087" p6:verwerkingssoort="W">
                    <inhoud p10:contentType="text/plain" p6:bestandsnaam="hallo 2.txt" xmlns:p10="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">aGFsbG8gZGFhciB4DQoNCg0K</inhoud>
                </object>
            </edcLk02>
        </updateZaakdocument_Di02>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php

    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $namespaces = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);

    $body = $sxe->xpath('//s:Body')[0];

    $inhoud = $body->updateZaakdocument_Di02->edcLk02->object->inhoud->children($namespaces["p10"]);
    print_r($inhoud);
```

the result is:

> SimpleXMLElement Object
>   (
>       [@attributes] => Array
>           (
>               [contentType] => text/plain
>           )
>   )

I tried from there:

```
echo (string) $inhoud >attributes($namespaces["p10"], true)->contentType;
```

But never get the value out of it.
Warning: Node no longer exists in the line above

Can someone point me to the right solution here?
Thanks in advance (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when your fetching the $inhoud value, your fetching the children in the p10 namespace.  What instead you need to do is fetch the attributes in the p10 namespace...

```
$inhoud = $body->updateZaakdocument_Di02->edcLk02->object->inhoud;
print_r($inhoud);

echo "contentType=".(string)$inhoud->attributes($namespaces["p10"])->contentType;
```

This outputs...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => aGFsbG8gZGFhciB4DQoNCg0K
)
contentType=text/plain
```

Also when using the various methods using namespaces, the second parameter is to flag that your using the prefix.  When using `$namespaces["p10"]` this is the URI and so you should leave the second parameter out.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `->attributes($namespaces["p10"])` can be simplified to `->attributes("p10", true)`; it's probably based on an old example from before that argument existed, and achieves exactly the same thing. Better yet, hard-code the actual namespace URI somewhere, e.g. `define('XMLNS_MIME', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime'); ... $inhoud->attributes(XMLNS_MIME) ...` - the reason being that `p10` is probably an auto-generated prefix that might change because of some tweak at the other end, whereas the URI should remain constant because it has a defined meaning.